# Run multiple task-definition using docker-compose.yml and ecs-params.yml file in AWS ECS with different lauch type and volume mounting

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, aws-cli, amazon-ecs, elastic-container-registry

I have 4 docker images which i want to run on ECS. For my local system i use docker-compose file where i have multiple services.

I want to do similar docker compose on ECS.

I want my database image to run on EC2 and rest on fargate and host the volume of database on EC2 and make sure each container can communicate with each-other using their name.
How do i configure my docker-compose.yml and ecs-param.yml file??

My sample docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  first:
    image: first:latest
    ports:
      - "2222:2222"
    depends_on:
       database:
        condition: service_healthy

  second:
    image: second:latest
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    depends_on:
       database:
        condition: service_healthy

  third:
    image: third:latest
    ports:
      - "3333:3333"

  database:
    image: database
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: abcde
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: abcde
      MYSQL_USER: user
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./datadir/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
            timeout: 5s
            retries: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't see how you connect containers with each other.
   `depends_on` just tells Docker Compose the order to use when
   containers are started.
   You may have actual connection hardcoded inside containers, that's not good.
2. Assuming Docker Compose file you shared containers can reach each
   other using their aliases from Compose file.
   For example `third` container can use `database` domain name to reach 
   `database` container.
   So if you have such names hardcoded in your containers, it will work. However 
   usually people configure connection points(URLs) as environment variables in 
   Docker Compose file. In this case there is nothing hardcoded.
3. Hosting DB volume on EC2 can be a bad idea.
   EC2 has 2 types of storage mapping - EBS and instance (based on S3). Instance 
   storage is destroyed when EC2 instance is terminated. EBS has data preserves on 
   EBS always.
   So you either use EBS storage (and not EC2) or S3 that is not suitable for your 
   need here.
4. Hosting DB in a container is very bad idea.
   You can find the same info in a description of many DB images in Docker Hub.
   Instead you can use [MySql as a service using AWS RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/).
5. The problem you have now has nothing common with AWS and ECS
   now.
   When you have Docker Compose running fine locally, you will
   get the same on ECS side.

You can see example of configuration via Compose file [here](https://github.com/laptevn/jogging/blob/master/docker-compose.yml).